# Display Text from Input-Select field

Tags: php, html, select, input

I have a form saving to PHP, which includes the following select input:

```
<label for="category">
    <span>Event Type :</span>
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="1"> Meeting</option>
        <option value="2"> Clean Up</option>
        <option value="3"> High Priority</option>
        <option value="4"> Special Projects</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

The saved that is then displayed on another page, but instead of displaying the `option value`, I want it to display the text value - ie. "Meeting", instead of "1"

The script that gets the data from the DB is:

```
// Get markers from XML - (event_data.php)
    $.get("./php/event_data.php", function (data) {
        $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
              var name = $(this).attr('name');
              var description = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('description') +'</p>';
              var type = $(this).attr('category');
              var edate = $(this).attr('edate');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat($(this).attr('lat')),parseFloat($(this).attr('lon')));
              create_marker(point, name, description, edate, type, false, false, false, '');
        });
    });
```

And is displayed with this:

```
var eventContent = $('<div class="event-details">' +
        '<h3>Event Details</h3><table class="table">' +
        '<tr><th>Event Name: </th><td>' + eName + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Event Date: </th><td>' + eDate + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Event Type: </th><td>' + type + '</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Event Details: </th><td>' + eForm + '</td></tr>' +
        '</table></div>'
        );
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make value = Meeting, Clean Up, etc?

Comment: Could you show the code displaying `1` ?

Comment: @fxm I have amended the original question

Comment: @jackel414 I would rather not as I already have stuff saved to the DB using these values

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make an php array - the key of the array can be the option value(eg. 1, 2, 3...) and the value can be the text that you want to show.

```
$categories = [1=>"Meeting", 2=>"Clean up"];
echo ($categories[$_GET['category']]);
```

Depending of the case it can be much better to have your categories into a database. The value of the options to be the id of the category. Using that approach when you need to show the name of the category you can get it from the database by the id.
Note: If you have relations between categories and something else in the database It is better to make One to Many or Many to Many database relations. And then you can use SQL JOIN syntax to select combined rows from different tables.